# Are the ice-cream scenes foreshadowing something?

Tags: analysis, better-call-saul

In *Better Call Saul* S05E01, we see Saul Goodman drop his ice cream cone and go with Nacho Vargas. In  S05E02, we see multiple scenes of that dropped ice cream, notable the starting one with ants eating (rather attacking) the ice cream. Is it some kind of foreshadowing?

Comment: I'd say more symbolism than foreshadowing. In the world Jimmy's involved himself in, if something attractive is left at all vulnerable, very soon the ants will notice and devour it. Jimmy's the ice cream, and Albuquerque's various aspiring drug dealers are the ants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alan Sepinwall has some thoughts on [the symbolism of the ice cream](https://www.rollingstone.com/tv-movies/tv-movie-recaps/better-call-saul-recap-season-5-episode-3-guy-for-this-958780/):

> the symbolism’s not hard to miss: Jimmy has cast aside something sweet (a relatively honest legal career like the one he had before the war with Chuck) for something destructive, and he’s as oblivious to the carnage he’s starting to cause as the passers-by on the street are to what’s happening down at ant level.

Like when he was removing masking tape from Chuck's wood panelling, Jimmy's taken a shortcut (dumping an ice cream on the pavement, rather than finding a trash can) – albeit this time, under pressure from the cartel – and there are damaging consequences. (Although, thankfully, [not for the ant actors](https://www.rollingstone.com/tv-movies/tv-movie-news/better-call-saul-ant-wrangler-964304/).)

Ice cream is also present when

> Kim has the fateful idea of [discrediting Howard to prompt settlement of the Sandpiper case](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Something_Unforgivable#Act_IV),

and

> [a weekly pint of ice cream](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Saul_Gone#Act_IV) during his 90-month prison sentence is the last concession Saul is eager to wring from the government in the series finale.

So I dunno, maybe it's like oranges in *The Godfather* trilogy, [which got a reference in *Breaking Bad*](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Ted_Beneke#Trivia).

Answer (score 4):

It likely doesn't foreshadow anything. The mint chocolate chip ice cream cone is Jimmy treating himself to his favorite after a job well done (in his opinion), and that moment of joy gets spoiled by him becoming entangled with the cartel.

Comment: Don't Saul and Kim eat ice cream together earlier in the season? I vaguely recall Saul calling dibs on "mint chocolate chip" or "mint chip". The dropped/melted cone could be some kind of metaphor for their relationship, or his tenuous friendship with the cartel.